# trouble with html form

Tags: html, forms, action

I try to create a `form` with a button as an image. My problem is that it does not appear.

```
<form style="text-align: center:" action="http://foo.net/foo" method="post">
    <input style="border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; width: 250px; padding: 3px; font-size: 25px;" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" size="24" onfocus="this.value='';" />
    <input style="width: 250px; height: 100px; border: 0; background-color: #fff;" type="image" alt="free cookies" src="/files/2013/09/button-cookies.gif" />
</form>
```

Is there something wrong in the Code?

Comment: Look at the Net tab in your browser's developer tools. Can you see the request for the image? Do you get a 200 OK response?

Comment: `coockies.gif` did you misspell cookies?

Comment: @j08691 fixed (it was only as for an example)

Comment: @Quentin the image does not appear in my browser dev-tools

Comment: @KrishR changing the pass have no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with WordPress! sry for this. After saving the code between the form will be deleted. it was a problem with rights.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here:

```
"text-align: center:"
```

remove ":" in the end... Perhaps will help.

Also recheck your image path

Comment: No. That would cause it to be misaligned, it wouldn't prevent it from being rendered altogether.